# Divs in one section disappear immediately after load of page with flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having this really weird issue with a `flexbox` based web page I'm working on. Everything is working fine except that the divs contained in the `<aside>` flash on the screen for a second when the page loads before disappearing. I've hosted the page [here](https://mikeholygrail.herokuapp.com/) to test.

For the sake of brevity, I won't post the entire code here because it can be easily checked in context using developer tools on the page itself.
But here is an excerpt of the section of HTML where the problem is occurring.

```
<aside class="HolyGrail-ads">
      aside section
      <div id="ads-wrap">
        <h3>Ad Column</h3>
        <div class="ad">
          <h4>Ad One Title</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</aside>
```

Just on a side note, the page works absolutely fine on my machine so I have no idea what's causing this bug when it's hosted. I have tried pushing to `gh-pages` and the `Heroku` but it didn't make any difference.

I'm just getting started with flexbox so maybe it's something I've left out on the `<aside>` section that is causing this? Or maybe it's some other glaring error. All suggestions appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try renaming the divs, especially removing the `ads-wrap` and `ad` class? Some ad blocking mechanism of your web browser might be blocking them. AdBlock Plus is blocking them by default.

Comment: Well spotted. It's the Ad Block that is doing it! Completely overlooked that. Thanks for the speedy fix!